# css or react Keep border focus when clicking my eye button

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I have a login page where I set border colors on focus and I want to keep the focus even when I'm clicking my eye password toggle[I have attached a gif that shows how I loose my focus state when toggling my eye](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3omo1.gif)

Comment: I don't know if this is possible using css or react , because I cant think of any solution to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to store a ref to the password input field, and call `focus()` on it in the eye's `onClick` handler:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";

const Eye = ({ onClick }) => <span onClick={onClick}>eye</span>;

export default function App() {
  const inputRef = useRef();

  const handleEyeClick = () => {
    if (inputRef.current) {
      inputRef.current.focus();
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input ref={inputRef} type="text" />
      <Eye onClick={handleEyeClick} />
    </div>
  );
}
```